# Import svg files with gradients and textures

Tags: jquery, svg, raphael, textures, gradient

I am using the library [raphael-svg-import-classic](https://github.com/crccheck/raphael-svg-import-classic).

Anyone know how do I import svg files with gradients and textures?

I use the same code that I used at my company, (the same, I think so , now I can no longer access it but the code I'm using is using the same library raphael svg import classic).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "assets/demo.svg",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(svgXML) {
        var paper = Raphael(10, 10, 800, 600);
        var newSet = paper.importSVG(svgXML);
        }
    });
});
```

In the debugger there is no error, I can import the file but the svg element is without texture and gradient.

Comment: what problem do you have compared to import an svg files without gradient or texture ? what have you tried ?

Comment: I try import svg files with textures and gradients of illustrator but i can't.

Comment: maybe you could show us the svg code, or the content of the svg file you are refering to.

Comment: when you say "I try to import" => what do you try, what code do you write, what operation do you do ? when you say "but i can't" what is the error message, is it only by eye that you see no gradient, where do you see that result, in a browser, in a application. You just give us really not enough information.

Comment: I have the code in the company and now can not access but the code I'm using is the same library raphael svg import classic. In the debugger there is no error, I can import the file but the svg element is without texture and gradient.

Comment: I have edited your question with the needed elements you gave us. However, you still don't tell us in which browser do you see the error ?

Comment: And could you paste the svg code please, or at least a link like on [http://pastebin.com] for the file `assets/demo.svg` where you'd paste the file content. We should check that the demo file is valid.

Comment: You can edit you question to add further detail. Click edit under the tags of your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is my js code.

As I mentioned before the element appears but not the textures and gradients.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mouseHover(svgObjects){
        var mouseover = function (event) {
            this.attr({opacity:0.8});
        }
        var mouseout = function (event) {
            this.attr({opacity:1});
        }
        svgObjects.hover(mouseover, mouseout);
    }

    function dragNdrop(paper, newSet, svgObjects){
        var posX = 't' + svgObjects.getBBox().x;
        var posY = svgObjects.getBBox().y;

        mouseHover(svgObjects);

        var start = function () {
            this.ox = 0;
            this.oy = 0;
        },
        move = function (dx, dy) {
            var objectScale = this.matrix.a;
            var trans_x = dx-this.ox;
            var trans_y = dy-this.oy;
            if(((this.matrix.e>0) 
                    && (this.matrix.e+this.getBBox().width)<paper.width
                    && (this.matrix.f>0) 
                    && (this.matrix.f+this.getBBox().height)<paper.height
                )){
                this.translate(trans_x/objectScale,trans_y/objectScale);
                if(((this.matrix.e>newSet.getBBox().x) 
                    && (this.matrix.e+this.getBBox().width)<newSet.getBBox().x2
                    && (this.matrix.f>newSet.getBBox().y) 
                    && (this.matrix.f+this.getBBox().height)<newSet.getBBox().y2
                )){
                    newSet.attr({opacity:0.7});
                }else{
                    newSet.attr({opacity:1});
                }
            }
            this.ox = dx;
            this.oy = dy;
        },
        up = function () {
            if(!((this.matrix.e>newSet.getBBox().x) 
                    && (this.matrix.e+this.getBBox().width)<newSet.getBBox().x2
                    && (this.matrix.f>newSet.getBBox().y) 
                    && (this.matrix.f+this.getBBox().height)<newSet.getBBox().y2
                )){
                this.animate({
                    transform: '"' + posX + ',' + posY + ',s1' + '"'
                }, 500, 'easeIn');   
            }else{
                newSet.attr({opacity:1});
            }
        };
        paper.set(svgObjects).drag(move, start, up);
    }

    function getSVG(url){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "images/tshirt.svg",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(svgXML) {
                var width = 1024; 
                var height = 768;
                var paper = Raphael('tela', width, height);
                var newSet = paper.importSVG(svgXML);
                var basePlusValue = newSet.getBBox().width;
                var centerBase = (width/2)-(basePlusValue/2);
                newSet.translate(centerBase, 20);
                newSet.attr({id : 'base'});
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function(svgComponent) {
                        var newComponent = paper.importSVG(svgComponent);
                        var spacePaperToElement = newComponent.getBBox().width*2;
                        newComponent.translate(centerBase + spacePaperToElement, 20);
                        newComponent.attr({cursor: "pointer"});
                        dragNdrop(paper, newSet, newComponent);
                        var texture1 = paper.image('images/textures/text1.jpg', centerBase + spacePaperToElement, 160, 100, 100);
                        texture1.attr({cursor: "pointer"});
                        mouseHover(texture1);
                        function handler(){
                            var cloneTexture1 = this.clone();
                            cloneTexture1.translate(-500, -100);
                            cloneTexture1.attr({opacity:1});
                            texture1.unclick(handler);
                        }
                        texture1.click(handler);

                    }
                });
            }
        }); 
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        getSVG("images/horse.svg");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried showing images/tshirt.svg and images/horse.svg by yourself in you prefered browser? What brother do you use ? Chrome and opera are well known for being rather up to date for some svg. Maybe you use the offending IE6 :-)

Comment: I use the chrome browser. But I researched better about this situation and the library raphael-import-svg does not allow importing textures and gradients.

Comment: that's strange... svg content is just xml... why don't you load it yourself and include it in the dom document of your page?